# Vote Count Padding on Flag Summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The vote count padding for items in the Flag History seems to have been adjusted with the recent CSS update.

The numbers are sitting at the bottom of the box, instead of the middle.

[image: vote count padding]

```
.flagged-post .answer-votes {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 23px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Changing the `padding-top` from `3px` to `1px` seems to fix the issue.

[image: vote count padding fixed]

Also, some of the new vote count boxes throughout the site are rounded, while these ones are square.

Can we please have a consistent design?

[image]

Comment: +1 for consistent design (which I imagine will come in the next few hours/days as they continue to fix the new CSS).

Comment: It seems they're rolling out the update in several steps, not every part of the site changes in the same time. It looks fine to me now.

Comment: @marcias I'm not seeing any changes? http://i.stack.imgur.com/dU7jq.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now, it will be live after our next production build.